# Get SelectedObject Index in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

This is my code:

```
var _ndcAccounts = new List<Account>();
objectListView1.SetObjects(_ndcAccounts);
```

Now, I want to give the user ability to add, edit and remove items using an ObjectListView.

Adding and removing are pretty straight forward. But for editing, I need to do:

```
_ndcAccounts[_ndcAccounts.FindIndex(account => account == (Account)objectListView1.SelectedObject)] = new Account();
```

Is there any way to find the selected object's index in the list more easily? The ObjectListView could be sorted or filtered.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't ObjectListView have a SelectedIndex property?  var account = _ndcAccounts[objectListView1.SelectedIndex];

Comment: I suggest to just use olv.SelectedObjects(). Working with indexes get get messy when you access underlying collections and use sorting or virtual views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that `_ndcAccounts` is the `List<Account>` then all you need to do is this.

```
int index = _ndcAccounts.IndexOf((Account)objectListView1.SelectedObject);
//Modify as you see fit
_ndcAccounts[index] = new Account();
```

If all you want to do is modify properties in the Account object without assigning that index in the list a new account object then all you need to do is directly modify `objectListView1.SelectedObject` since it should be a reference to the currently selected `Account` in the list and any modifications to it will reflect in the list (except creating a new instance of Account)

I don't know the structure of `Account` but here is an example anyway.

```
((Account)objectListView1.SelectedObject).Name = "My New Account";
```

The above would modify the Account object with the new Name and it will reflect as such in the list as well since you are actually modifying the item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a SelectedIndices property as in ListView? Something like this:

```
ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indexes = 
    objectListView1.SelectedIndices;

Account selectedAccount = objectListView1.Items[indexes.Items[0]];
```

You would need to check if selectedAccount is not null. Also if there are more than one account selected, you may need to handle this with a `foreach` loop on indexes to get a list of selected accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me from the olv event(CellEditFinished).

e.ListViewItem.Index